# How to Run a Mongoose Find inside a Foreach synchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, foreach

I have a query for a collection "Case" and for each record i need to match another collection "CustomerAgreement" .
So i'm using forEach and calling the 2nd query inside it. The problem is that the query runs after the forEach ends.

Lets say there are 5 Cases.

```
Case.find({},{case_id:1}).then(recs=>{
     recs.forEach(function(rec){
         console.log("x");
         CustomerAgreement.findOne({case_id:rec.case_id}).then(t=>{
             console.log("y");
         });
     });

     console.log("z");
});
```

The result im getting is (assuming there are 5 Cases)
x
x
x
x
x
z
y
y
y
y
y

The result i want is
x
y
x
y
x
y
x
y
x
y
z

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **async** function and the **await** each query in a loop:

```
Case
  .find({}, { case_id: 1 })
  .then(async (recs) => {

    for (const rec of recs) {
      console.log("x");

      const t = await CustomerAgreement
        .findOne({ case_id: rec.case_id })
        .exec();

      console.log("y");
    }

    console.log("z");
  });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do you read the const t variable?
When I do console.log(t)
it shows [object Object]

Comment: Try adding **exec**: `.findOne({ ... }).exec()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to use async / await you can use `for of` loop

```
const recs = await Case.find({}, {case_id: 1});

for (const rec of recs) {
  console.log("x");

  const t = await CustomerAgreement.findOne({ case_id: rec.case_id }).exec();
  console.log("y");
}

console.log("z");
```

if not, you can use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html), is a library that allows you to do that kind of operations.

```
Case.find({}, { case_id: 1 }).then((recs) => {
  async.each(recs, (rec, callback) => {
    console.log("x");
    CustomerAgreement.findOne({ case_id : rec.case_id }).then((t) => {
      console.log("y");
      callback();
    });
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('all records found successfully');
      console.log("z");
    }
  });
});
```

PD: I did not test the code above, but in theory should work.

Comment: this still doesnt work. it first prints all the "X"s in the for loop and then prints the "Y"s
in the CustomerAgreement.findOne .
what i need is, the moment the 1st loop runs i want the CustomerAgreement.findOne to run along with it.
what happens now is that the loop finishes 1st and after that CustomerAgreement.findOne finishes.